# How to set attributes in vaadin components?

Tags: gwt, vaadin, vaadin7

In GWT , I can add my custom properties or attributes in widgets.

```
    Widget widget = new Widget();
    widget.getElement().setAttribute("seq", "1001");
    System.out.println(widget.getElement().getAttribute("seq"));
```

Can I also add like this in vaadin's components ? If yes , how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

informations in general are transported by the "state" from the server/java-side to the client.  [Component](https://www.vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Component.html) has lots of trivial accessors for the most common problems (e.g. adding stylesheets).  if you want to write your own widgets/components and pass your own data along the state, there are good examples in the wiki e.g. https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Integrating%20a%20JavaScript%20component.

Comment: Yes , Thank you. Here is I referenced http://morevaadin.com/content/using-gwt-widgets-part-2/

Answer (score 2):

Try :

```
public static final String SET_ATTRIBUTE_QUERY = "var ary = document.getElementsByClassName('%s'); var index; for(index = 0; index < ary.length; index++) {ary[index].setAttribute('%s', '%s')}";

// For TextField        JavaScript.getCurrent().execute(String.format(SET_ATTRIBUTE_QUERY, "v-textfield", "autocomplete", "off"));

// For ComboBox    JavaScript.getCurrent().execute(String.format(SET_ATTRIBUTE_QUERY, "v-filterselect-input", "autocomplete", "off"));
```

Comment: This solution is not pretty, but it's the one that worked for me.